# Angular Material DatePicker -- Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want add a date picker to select a date range.

### App module

```
MatFormFieldModule,
MatDatepickerModule,
MatInputModule,
```

### Form

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" #arrival>
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" #departure>
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) provide the following error description:

> **Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl**
>
> This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form
> field. If your form field contains a native `<input>` or `<textarea>`
> element, make sure you've added the `matInput` directive to it and have
> imported `MatInputModule`. Other components that can act as a form field
> control include `<mat-select>`, `<mat-chip-list>`, and any custom form
> field controls you've created.

The `matInput` directive needs to be added to the `<input>` elements.

To select a date range using two date-pickers, place each date-picker within its own `mat-form-field`. See Angular example [**Datepicker palette colors**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkkabjyadxly?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-color-example.html)

### Example

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: my mistake was to use '<mat-input >' instead of '<input matInput>'  EXAMPLE: <mat-form-field> <!-- this works, not using the '<mat-input>'' --> <input matInput [formControl]="nameFilter" name="name-filter" /> <!-- below does not work: gives error 'Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.' --> <!-- <mat-input [formControl]="nameFilter" name="name-filter"></mat-input> --> </mat-form-field>